# How to convert varchar to time hh:mm

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

I have varchars representing military times:

```
a 2130 -- 21 hours
b 103 -- 1 hour
c 10  -- 10 minutes
d 1  -- 1 minutes
```

the left two characters always represent minutes.  In example c and c above 10 and 1 are always minutes.  example b 103 has three characters.  1 is hour 03 is minute in this case.

How do I convert this into time hh:mm format?

Comment: Like `STUFF(RIGHT('0000' + str, 4), 3, 0, ':')`?

Comment: How is 103 equal to "1 hour"?

Comment: And do you mean the *right two characters* represent the minutes?

Comment: Have a look into my answer it will also work for data type varchar.

Comment: Do you want a `time` value or just a string with that format? The version of SQL Server matters too.

Answer (score 3):

One option is use to use Format()

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol int)
Insert into @YourTable values
 (2130)
,(103)
,(10)
,(1)

Select SomeCol
      ,TimeValue = format(SomeCol,'00:00')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol TimeValue
2130    21:30
103     01:03
10      00:10
1       00:01
```

> **EDIT - Requested EDIT for 2008**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol int)
Insert into @YourTable values
 (2130)
,(103)
,(10)
,(1)

Select SomeCol
      ,TimeValue = stuff(right('0000' + left(SomeCol, 4),4), 3, 0, ':')
 From  @YourTable
```

Comment: It seems good solution but getting error in SQL Server 2008 R2: "'format' is not a recognized built-in function name.". So please suggest if it is valid for a specific version of SQL Server.

Comment: points to thing about: `(1)` FORMAT does not CONVERT the type into TIME as the title of the question requested. Moreover, this query will not even return VARCHAR but NVARCHAR - you can confirm this using `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY (format(SomeCol,'00:00'),'BaseType') FROM   @YourTable`. This mean that instead of passing to the client 3 Byte which is what time(0) cost, we pass from the server a string type NVARCHAR with 5 characters which is 10 Bytes. This is a huge different which can dramatically impact performance.

Comment: `(2)` You should really think about re-design your system (database and client app which use it) and think about storing the data as time(0) instead of fighting the server and spend time and performance on workaround soutions

Comment: @BrijeshKumarTripathi See EDIT for 2008 version

Comment: @BrijeshKumarTripathi Happy to help.   Tell your DBA that Extended Support for 2008 will end in July 2019

Comment: Our DBA team is working to upgrade it. Thanks once again for your helping gesture!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following using length of column value and case statement.

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol int)
Insert into @YourTable values
 (2130)
,(103)
,(10)
,(1)

Select 
    case LEN(SomeCol)
        when 4 then SUBSTRING('2130', 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING('2130', 3, 2)
        when 3 then '0' + SUBSTRING('103', 1, 1) + ':' + SUBSTRING('103', 2, 2)
        when 2 then '00:' + CONVERT(Varchar(5), SomeCol)
        else '00:0' + CONVERT(Varchar(5), SomeCol)
    end as TimeValue
from @YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day Jacob,

Please check if this solution fit you:

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol int)
Insert into @YourTable values
 (2130)
,(103)
,(10)
,(1)
--Select SomeCol,TimeValue = format(SomeCol,'00:00'), SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY (format(SomeCol,'00:00'),'BaseType')
--From  @YourTable
SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0),TIMEFROMPARTS(ROUND(SomeCol/100,0), SomeCol%100,0,0,0))
FROM @YourTable
```

Ops, I notice new information in the comments. Seems like you use SQL Server 2008R2 and TIMEFROMPARTS will not work on SQL Server2008r2 (only starting with 2012)...I will edit the answer in a second

**Note!** I highly recommend to re-think about your database design.Please read the comment I wrote above for more information

Update:

```
-- For old servers please check if one of these this fit you
SELECT --RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),ROUND(SomeCol/100,0)),2),RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),SomeCol%100),2),
    CONVERT(TIME(0),RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),ROUND(SomeCol/100,0)),2) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),SomeCol%100),2))
FROM @YourTable
```